# How to remove warning for spaces on newlines in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

I'm currently working with .properties files to change some texts to be displayed in the software and I came across this:
[image]

It highlights a newline (which is not a space) at the end of a line even though the newline is needed here.

How do I get rid of the warning without getting rid of the newline AND without sacrificing the functionality of IntelliJ removing actual trailing spaces when I save a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings of the inspection there is a checkbox `Ignore visible whitespaces`. Enabling this option will stop the inspection from warning on `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

This inspection can be disabled/changed under `Settings | Editor | Inspections | Properties files | Trailing spaces in property`:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful but does not completely answer the question. I would like to be warned about whitespaces (like before) but not about newlines.